# What is TextFragement in lucene?

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch, lucene

I don't understand , what are the TextFragment in Lucene  Highlighter ? What are the benefits of Lucene's TextFragments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text fragments are the fragments of field content that matches the query and must be highlighted.
For example, considering you have the field:
`"title": "Back to the future"`.
If you search for `back` Lucene will retrieve you one **TextFragment** object with `markedUpText: back`, `textStartPos: 0` and `fragNum: 4`. It means that the highlighted text `back` matches on the field `title` in the position `0` and contains `4` fragments.

Comment: if the searched term is repeated in the field what would be the fragments result

Comment: Lucene will retrieve you a list of TextFragments. For example, if you have a field `"title": "End to end"` and you search for `end` Lucene will retrieve you a list with two TextFragment objects one starting in the position `0` and the other starting in the position `7`, both with the text `end`. Independent if the term occurs more than one time, each one is a different fragment in the sentence.